# Can cable modem (with no router) get infected?

Tags: virus

Can an old cable modem, that has no in-built router, get infected by anything?

If yes, would there be obvious signs of its compromise? Could I make sure everything is okay? What could an infected modem potentially do?

Modem is Scientific Atlanta 2203, A Cisco Company.

Comment: Welcome to InfoSec SE! As a note, we would be able to answer you better if you would provide us with some specific about the age, type, brand of the modem and its firmware. Some modems can be hacked, but we can't tell in your case.

Comment: @J.A.K. Hello! I added more info: Modem is Scientific Atlanta 2203, A Cisco Company. I've had it for 8 years now.

Answer (score 2):

Any digital "modem" is a computer with firmware that has the potential to be misappropriated.

However, it isn't that likely to be honest. If you are concerned, you should probably try and persuade your cable company to replace it.

You could also simply put a router inside of it which is a common configuration for security. Many new-ish routers no longer have "modems" built in since both cable and broadband (e.g. FTTC) no longer need them as it is common for users to be presented with an ethernet connection.

Worth noting that certainly many broadband "modems" are actually routers with a fixed configuration set by the ISP. Not sure about cable modems I'm afraid having never used one.

Comment: Thank you for answering! How do you put router inside of it? My modem is Scientific Atlanta 2203 - would it be too old to do something like that?

Comment: A router is only a device that routes packets from one interface to another. So "nesting" them isn't difficult and is not dependent on the age of your existing device. In enterprises, it is common to have internal firewalls (which are also technically routers) nested like this in order to provide additional protection to certain parts of the network. What you would be doing is adding a router/firewall as effectively the only device on the LAN your external router is creating. Then you are moving all the other devices to sit under the internal router/firewall.